# How to refresh with a rest api hook with ReactJS

Tags: reactjs, rest, refresh

I made an fetch hook for my rest api in ReactJS.
I'm having two components.

1) list of countries

2) add country

After component (2) adds a country I want to tell to component (1) to reload the data. I'm using a useEffect on component 1 to retrieve the data.

I tried to trigger a refresh boolean on the props. The refresh will trigger but it's going to fast. Before the new data is in the database, the refresh happened so I'm not getting the new data.

Countries.js

```
function Countries() {
  const [addCountryVisible, setAddCountryVisible] = useState(false);
  const countriesApi = useFetch("country/getall");

  useEffect(() => {
    getCountries();
  }, []);

  function getCountries() {
    countriesApi.run();
  }
return ...
}
```

AddCountry.js

```
function AddCountry(props) {
  const [country, setCountry] = useState({
    name: "",
    flag: ""
  });

  const addCountryApi = useFetch("country/add", "POST");

  const active = props.visible ? "is-active" : null;

  const handleSubmit = evt => {
    evt.preventDefault();

    addCountryApi.run(country, props.setDone);
  };
return ...
}
```

useFetch.js

```
import { useState } from "react";
import { useAuth0 } from "./react-auth0-wrapper";

const useFetch = (url, method = "GET") => {
  const { loading, getTokenSilently } = useAuth0();
  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(false);
  const [data, setData] = useState();
  const [error, setError] = useState();

  const run = async data => {
    if (!loading && getTokenSilently) {
      setError();
      setIsLoading(true);
      try {
        const token = await getTokenSilently();
        const options = {
          method,
          headers: {
            "Content-Type": "application/json",
            Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`
          },
          body: JSON.stringify(data)
        };
        const response = await fetch("/api/" + url, options);
        const json = await response.json();
        setData(json);
      } catch (e) {
        setError(e.message);
      }
      setIsLoading(false);
    }
  };

  return { data, error, isLoading, run };
};

export default useFetch;
```

I expect to refresh the data from the useEffect to update AFTER the hook is finished with adding the country.

Comment: You need your state to change in order to rerender.

Comment: https://www.robinwieruch.de/react-hooks-fetch-data

Comment: I understand, but how can I make the state change after the call... If api is success --> then do a refresh.

Comment: Check out this video https://youtu.be/k0WnY0Hqe5c